# Convert list or numpy array of single element to float in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, floating-point

I have a function which can accept either a list or a numpy array.

In either case, the list/array has a single element (always). I just need to return a float.

So, e.g., I could receive:

```
list_ = [4]
```

or the numpy array:

```
array_ = array([4])
```

And I should return

```
 4.0
```

So, naturally (I would say), I employ float(...) on list_ and get:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

I do the same to array_ and this time it works by responding with "4.0". From this, I learn that Python's list cannot be converted to float this way.

Based on the success with the numpy array conversion to float this lead me to the approach:

```
float(np.asarray(list_))
```

And this works when list_ is both a Python list and when it is a numpy array.

**Question**

But it seems like this approach has an overhead first converting the list to a numpy array and then to float. Basically: Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Can't you use slicing: float(list_[0]) = 4.0

Comment: either  `float(list_[0])` or `float(''.join(list_))`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Just access the first item of the list/array, using the index access and the index 0:

```
>>> list_ = [4]
>>> list_[0]
4
>>> array_ = np.array([4])
>>> array_[0]
4
```

This will be an `int` since that was what you inserted in the first place. If you need it to be a float for some reason, you can call `float()` on it then:

```
>>> float(list_[0])
4.0
```

Comment: @Aaron Voelker has the best answer

Answer (score 57):

You may want to use the [`ndarray.item`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) method, as in `a.item()`. This is also equivalent to (the now deprecated) [`np.asscalar(a)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asscalar.html). This has the benefit of working in situations with views and superfluous axes, while the above solutions will currently break. For example,

```
>>> a = np.asarray(1).view()
>>> a.item()  # correct
1

>>> a[0]  # breaks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for array


>>> a = np.asarray([[2]])
>>> a.item()  # correct
2

>>> a[0]  # bad result
array([2])
```

This also has the benefit of throwing an exception if the array is not actually a scalar, while the `a[0]` approach will silently proceed (which may lead to bugs sneaking through undetected).

```
>>> a = np.asarray([1, 2])
>>> a[0]  # silently proceeds
1
>>> a.item()  # detects incorrect size
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

Answer (score 10):

Use [numpy.asscalar](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asscalar.html) to convert a numpy array / matrix a scalar value:

```
>>> a=numpy.array([[[[42]]]])
>>> numpy.asscalar(a)
42
```

> The output data type is the same type returned by the input’s `item` method.

It has built in error-checking if there is more than an single element:

```
>>> a=numpy.array([1, 2])
>>> numpy.asscalar(a)
```

gives:

```
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

---

Note: the object passed to `asscalar` must respond to `item`, so passing a list or tuple won't work.

Comment: Deprecated since version 1.16: Deprecated, use numpy.ndarray.item() instead.

Answer (score 5):

`np.asscalar(a)` is deprecated since NumPy v1.16, use `a.item()` instead.

For example:

```
a = np.array([[0.6813]])
print(a.item())
```

gives:

```
0.6813
```

Answer (score 4):

I would simply use,

```
np.asarray(input, dtype=np.float)[0]
```

- If `input` is an `ndarray` of the right dtype, there is no overhead, since `np.asarray` does nothing in this case.
- if `input` is a `list`, `np.asarray` makes sure the output is of the right type.